# Sort strings numbers, like integer numbers in JQGrid

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

I had a jqgrid with float numbers. I tried to get rid of the right side 0 and group the numbers, so those are now like (for example: "123,242"), and you know that the type of them are now String.
I want to sort theme like integer numbers in jqgrid.
what should I do?

> for example a part of a column
>   after sort(asc) these strings are like
>   this:
>
> 1,959
>
> 1,965
>
> 1,989
>
> 10,235
>
> 100
>
> 100
>
> ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you implemented the indexing and sorting according to jqGrid document. For example: http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=254

I assume you retrieved data from database. If you’ve followed those already, moreover, you may need to CAST or CONVERT that particular database field from STRING or VARCHAR into INT or NUMERIC when you bind your SQL query.

jqGrid is powerful to do rest of things automatically.

Answer (score -2):

You can zero-pad them (e.g. 00100 and 01959), sort them, and then remove the padding.  Computer Programming 0101.

Comment: thanks buddy, But I mentioned JQGrid. In a grid, user should choose which column to sort.